# Why did Dracule Mihawk become a Warlord/Shichibukai?

Tags: one-piece

If we see the list of Shichibukai, almost all of them have some reason to become Shichibukai.

Boa Hancock became shichibukai to protect Amazon Lily from marine. Gekko Morai, Doflamingo, Crocodile etc had their black work or evil deeds, which needed to be protected from marine.

But I don't remember anything about the Mihawk. He is alone but strong, so he don't need to fear from marine.

What is his real intention to become warlord?

Comment: We don't know much about his motivations at all...Jimbe was like Hancock right? Protecting Fishman island?

Comment: @kaine yes, and Mihawk appearance in one piece is as few as Shanks with very little information..

Comment: Yeah we do not have that much info about Mihawk, maybe he was never even a pirate in the right sense. Regarding the title of Shichibukai, even if you are strong you will be a wanted man. Maybe the regular marines wont be after you but surely you could come across someone like Akainu or Kizaru which could cause problems, maybe even more for someone like Mihawk who seems to operate alone.

Comment: Boredom? Wanting to keep the weaklings away from him and only being chased by strong people, because fighting a strong opponent kills some time and some boredom.

Comment: it is possible that he actually just wanted the title since there's no real reason not to, after all, he could just not show up to a fight if he didn't want to. Not everyone has to be a warlord because they have some illegal past, and aside from going around talking to pirates with no apparent goal he doesn't seem to be doing anything illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how there is no motivation stated in the canon for Mihawk becoming a Shichibukai, I assume his reason to ally with the Government was to be able to access assets that would be reserved for members of the World Government only, such as the Tarai Current or passing from Paradise to New World via Mariejois, thus allowing him more freedom of movement. Mihawk reminds me of the wandering swordsman, so more freedom of movement sounds like something he might be interested in

Answer (score 1):

Oda hasn't shown anything about his backstory, but there are hints as to why he became a Shichibukai.

My first guess comes from the illustration of Mihawk as a child. Here, it's shown that he's been involved in warfare since childhood, thus it probably got the attention of the government since long ago. We don't even know if he was a pirate, to begin with, but imagine having the title of the strongest swordsman the marines would eventually look for him.

Later, there's the flashback of Roger's execution. At this point, he looks unbeatable and probably a Shichibukai by then.

Mihawk is lonely and looks like he wants to be left in peace in the country where he resides, so my conclusion is that: he became a Shichibukai to be left alone, and also what [Shifty's answer stated](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/44807/2516) that he also seems to want to freely move and why not obtain assets from the title.